# spring data JPA optional.orelse does not work correctly

Tags: spring-data-jpa

```
Country country = countryService.findCountryByName(DEFAULT_COUNTRY_NAME)
                    .orElse(countryService.create(createCountryEntity()));
```

Service:

```
public Optional<Country> findCountryByName(String name) {
        return dao.findByNameIgnoreCase(name);
    }

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Country create(Country country) {
    return dao.save(country);
}
```

Dao:

```
@Transactional
public interface CountryDao extends JpaRepository<Country, Integer> {
    Optional<Country> findByNameIgnoreCase(String name);
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
@Data
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "country_id", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "country_name")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 100)
    private String name;
}
```

I don't know why does `countryService.findCountryByName(DEFAULT_COUNTRY_NAME)
                    .orElse(countryService.create(createCountryEntity()));` always go into the `orElse` block even I verified the first part is present in the debugger.

How do I fix it?

Comment: How does your dao and your entity look like?

Comment: I've added entity and dao information.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know why does [...] always go into the orElse block even I verified the first part is present

That is just how Java works.
`orElse` is just a method, not a an if condition or something. 
Therefore its parameters will get evaluated before it gets called.

You probably want something like

```
Country country = countryService
        .findCountryByName(DEFAULT_COUNTRY_NAME)
        .orElseGet(() -> countryService.create(createCountryEntity()));
```